# How can I "reuse" code in XSL

Tags: xslt

I'm using XSLT node. My question is about XSL. I have searched on Internet, but I've only found info about XML processing for show it on a web page. Info I'm searching is how "reuse" some code in this scenario:

My XSL is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:wsb="http://tempuri.org/">

    <xsl:import href="HubGenerico.xsl" />

    <xsl:template match="/RCECSTD2">
        <xsl:element name="soap:Envelope">
            <xsl:element name="soap:Header" />
            <xsl:element name="soap:Body" />

            <xsl:choose>

                <xsl:when test="STDR2_DATOS_CONTROL/STDR2_CODOPE = 1010">
                    <xsl:element name="wsb:ConsultarSC">
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:codigoOperacion">
                            <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_CONTROL/STDR2_CODOPE" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:numeroOperacion">
                            <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_CONTROL/STDR2_NUMOPEBCO" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:codigoBanco">
                            <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_EMPRESA/STDR2_CODBCO" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:codigoConvenio">
                            <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_EMPRESA/STDR2_CODCONTR" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:numeroReferenciaDeuda">
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="normalize-space(STDR2_DATOS_TRANSACCION/STDR2_NUMREF_DEUDA)" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:canalOperacion">
                            <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_OPERACION/STDR2_CANAL" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:codigoOficina">
                            <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_OPERACION/STDR2_CODOFI" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:fechaOperacion">
                            <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_OPERACION/STDR2_FECOPE" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:horaOperacion">
                            <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_OPERACION/STDR2_HOROPE" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:datosEmpresa" />
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>

                <xsl:when test="STDR2_DATOS_CONTROL/STDR2_CODOPE = 2010">
                    <xsl:element name="wsb:NotificarPago">
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:codigoOperacion">
                            <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_CONTROL/STDR2_CODOPE" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:numeroOperacion">
                            <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_CONTROL/STDR2_NUMOPEBCO" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:codigoBanco">
                            <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_EMPRESA/STDR2_CODBCO" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:codigoConvenio">
                            <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_EMPRESA/STDR2_CODCONTR" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:otrosDatosEmpresa" />
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:numeroReferenciaDeuda">
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="normalize-space(STDR2_DATOS_TRANSACCION/STDR2_NUMREF_DEUDA)" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:NumDocDeuda">
                            <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:formaPago">
                            <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_TRANSACCION/STDR2_FORPAG" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:codigoMoneda">
                            <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_TRANSACCION/STDR2_CODMON" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:importeTotalPagado">
                            <xsl:variable name="importeTotalPagado">
                                <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="text"
                                        select="string(STDR2_DATOS_TRANSACCION/STDR2_IMPTOT_PAG)" />
                                    <xsl:with-param name="pattern" select="'.'" />
                                    <xsl:with-param name="replace-with" select="''" />
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$importeTotalPagado" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:detallePagoBBVA" />
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:canalOperacion">
                            <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_OPERACION/STDR2_CANAL" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:codigoOficina">
                            <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_OPERACION/STDR2_CODOFI" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:fechaOperacion">
                            <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_OPERACION/STDR2_FECOPE" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:horaOperacion">
                            <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_OPERACION/STDR2_HOROPE" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="wsb:datosEmpresa" />
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>

            </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You see that some created elements are "repeated" (same code) but they have differents parents (`ConsultarSC` and `NotificarPago`). So my question is how can I reuse that "repeated code", I don't if exists some "tag" that can I use how a "reference" (like ESQL).

Comment: search for `xslt call-template` and `xslt apply-template`

Comment: If the element names are known and do not need to be dynamically generated at execution time, literal result elements are easier to read and generally considered better style (i.e. use `<soap:Header/>` instead of `<xsl:element name="soap:Header" />` )

Answer (score 15):

In your example, "named" templates are you friend here. For example, if you wanted to create the same two elements in different places, create a named template like so

```
 <xsl:template name="exampleTemplate">
    <xsl:element name="wsb:codigoOperacion">
        <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_CONTROL/STDR2_CODOPE" />
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="wsb:numeroOperacion">
        <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_CONTROL/STDR2_NUMOPEBCO" />
    </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
```

Then, to create these two elements, just call the template like so:

```
<xsl:call-template name="exampleTemplate" />
```

And that's it!

Note, just like functions, you can pass parameters to templates too.

```
<xsl:template name="example">
    <xsl:param name="value" />
    Value is <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:call-template name="example">
    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="element" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

As an aside, there is no need to use **xsl:element** to create an element if you are using a static name, just write out element name directly.  So, instead of this

```
    <xsl:element name="wsb:numeroOperacion">
        <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_CONTROL/STDR2_NUMOPEBCO" />
    </xsl:element>
```

Just do this

```
    <wsb:numeroOperacion>
        <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_CONTROL/STDR2_NUMOPEBCO" />
    </wsb:numeroOperacion>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your output follows the same pattern with some extra stuff added in certain situations, you can have one template for the main layout, and then call off to other conditional templates for the extra stuff:

```
  <xsl:import href="HubGenerico.xsl" />

  <xsl:template match="/RCECSTD2">
    <soap:Envelope>
      <soap:Header />
      <soap:Body />

      <xsl:apply-templates select="STDR2_DATOS_CONTROL/STDR2_CODOPE" />
    </soap:Envelope>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Override the default handling of text nodes -->
  <xsl:template match="text()" />

  <xsl:template match="STDR2_CODOPE[. = 1010]">
    <wsb:ConsultarSC>
      <xsl:call-template name="Content" />
    </wsb:ConsultarSC>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="STDR2_CODOPE[. = 2010]">
    <wsb:NotificarPago>
      <xsl:call-template name="Content" />
    </wsb:NotificarPago>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="Content">
    <xsl:call-template name="Basic" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="otrosDatos" />
    <xsl:call-template name="NumeroDeuda" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="deudaPagado" />
    <xsl:call-template name="Operacion" />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Context node is STDR2_CODOPE -->
  <xsl:template name="Basic">
    <xsl:variable name="empresa" select="../../STDR2_DATOS_EMPRESA" />
    <wsb:codigoOperacion>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </wsb:codigoOperacion>
    <wsb:numeroOperacion>
      <xsl:value-of select="../STDR_NUMOPEBCO" />
    </wsb:numeroOperacion>
    <wsb:codigoBanco>
      <xsl:value-of select="$empresa/STDR2_CODBCO"/>
    </wsb:codigoBanco>
    <wsb:codigoConvenio>
      <xsl:value-of select="$empresa/STDR2_CODCONTR"/>
    </wsb:codigoConvenio>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="NumeroDeuda">
    <wsb:numeroReferenciaDeuda>
      <xsl:value-of 
        select="normalize-space(../../STDR2_DATOS_TRANSACCION/STDR2_NUMREF_DEUDA)"/>
    </wsb:numeroReferenciaDeuda>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="Operacion">
    <xsl:variable name="operacion" select="../../STDR2_DATOS_OPERACION" />

    <wsb:canalOperacion>
      <xsl:value-of select="$operacion/STDR2_CANAL" />
    </wsb:canalOperacion>
    <wsb:codigoOficina>
      <xsl:value-of select="$operacion/STDR2_CODOFI" />
    </wsb:codigoOficina>
    <wsb:fechaOperacion>
      <xsl:value-of select="$operacion/STDR2_FECOPE" />
    </wsb:fechaOperacion>
    <wsb:horaOperacion>
      <xsl:value-of select="$operacion/STDR2_HOROPE" />
    </wsb:horaOperacion>
    <wsb:datosEmpresa />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="STDR2_CODOPE[. = 2010]" mode="otrosDatos">
    <wsb:otrosDatosEmpresa />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="STDR2_CODOPE[. = 2010]" mode="deudaPagado">
    <xsl:variable name="transaccion" select="../../STDR2_DATOS_TRANSACCION" />

    <wsb:NumDocDeuda>1</wsb:NumDocDeuda>
    <wsb:formaPago>
      <xsl:value-of select="$transaccion/STDR2_FORPAG" />
    </wsb:formaPago>
    <wsb:codigoMoneda>
      <xsl:value-of select="$transaccion/STDR2_CODMON" />
    </wsb:codigoMoneda>
    <wsb:importeTotalPagado>
      <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
        <xsl:with-param name="text"
            select="string($transaccion/STDR2_IMPTOT_PAG)" />
        <xsl:with-param name="pattern" select="'.'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace-with" select="''" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </wsb:importeTotalPagado>
    <wsb:detallePagoBBVA />
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks "JLRishe" and "Tim C". My XSL files result in:

Principal:

`

```
<xsl:import href="HubGenerico.xsl" />
<xsl:variable name="myns" select="'http://tempuri.org/'" />

<xsl:template match="/RCECSTD2">
    <soap:Envelope>
        <soap:Header />
        <soap:Body />
        <xsl:variable name="codOperacion" select="STDR2_DATOS_CONTROL/STDR2_CODOPE" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$codOperacion = 1010">
                <wsb:ConsultarSC xmlns:wsb="'http://tempuri.org/'">
                    <xsl:call-template name="STDR2_DATOS_CONTROL">
                        <xsl:with-param name="ns" select="$myns" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <xsl:call-template name="STDR2_DATOS_EMPRESA">
                        <xsl:with-param name="ns" select="$myns" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <wsb:numeroReferenciaDeuda>
                        <xsl:value-of
                            select="normalize-space(STDR2_DATOS_TRANSACCION/STDR2_NUMREF_DEUDA)" />
                    </wsb:numeroReferenciaDeuda>
                    <xsl:call-template name="STDR2_DATOS_OPERACION">
                        <xsl:with-param name="ns" select="$myns" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <wsb:datosEmpresa />
                </wsb:ConsultarSC>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:when test="$codOperacion = 2010">
                <wsb:NotificarPago xmlns:wsb="$ns">
                    <xsl:call-template name="STDR2_DATOS_CONTROL">
                        <xsl:with-param name="ns" select="$myns" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <xsl:call-template name="STDR2_DATOS_EMPRESA">
                        <xsl:with-param name="ns" select="$myns" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <wsb:otrosDatosEmpresa />
                    <wsb:numeroReferenciaDeuda>
                        <xsl:value-of
                            select="normalize-space(STDR2_DATOS_TRANSACCION/STDR2_NUMREF_DEUDA)" />
                    </wsb:numeroReferenciaDeuda>
                    <wsb:NumDocDeuda>
                        <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
                    </wsb:NumDocDeuda>
                    <wsb:formaPago>
                        <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_TRANSACCION/STDR2_FORPAG" />
                    </wsb:formaPago>
                    <wsb:codigoMoneda>
                        <xsl:value-of select="STDR2_DATOS_TRANSACCION/STDR2_CODMON" />
                    </wsb:codigoMoneda>
                    <wsb:importeTotalPagado>
                        <xsl:variable name="importeTotalPagado">
                            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
                                <xsl:with-param name="text"
                                    select="string(STDR2_DATOS_TRANSACCION/STDR2_IMPTOT_PAG)" />
                                <xsl:with-param name="pattern" select="'.'" />
                                <xsl:with-param name="replace-with" select="''" />
                            </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$importeTotalPagado" />
                    </wsb:importeTotalPagado>
                    <wsb:detallePagoBBVA />
                    <xsl:call-template name="STDR2_DATOS_OPERACION">
                        <xsl:with-param name="ns" select="$myns" />
                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <wsb:datosEmpresa />
                </wsb:NotificarPago>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </soap:Envelope>
</xsl:template>
```

`

Imported XSL:

`

```
<xsl:template name="string-replace">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="pattern" />
    <xsl:param name="replace-with" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $pattern)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $pattern)" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$replace-with" />
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text"
                    select="substring-after($text, $pattern)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="pattern" select="$pattern" />
                <xsl:with-param name="replace-with" select="$replace-with" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Datos de Control -->
<xsl:template name="STDR2_DATOS_CONTROL">
    <xsl:param name="ns" />
    <xsl:variable name="datControl" select="STDR2_DATOS_CONTROL" />
    <xsl:element name="wsb:codigoOperacion" namespace="{$ns}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$datControl/STDR2_CODOPE" />
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="wsb:numeroOperacion" namespace="{$ns}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$datControl/STDR2_NUMOPEBCO" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Datos de Empresa -->
<xsl:template name="STDR2_DATOS_EMPRESA">
    <xsl:param name="ns" />
    <xsl:variable name="datEmpresa" select="STDR2_DATOS_EMPRESA" />
    <xsl:element name="wsb:codigoBanco" namespace="{$ns}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$datEmpresa/STDR2_CODBCO" />
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="wsb:codigoConvenio" namespace="{$ns}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$datEmpresa/STDR2_CODCONTR" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Datos de Operacion -->
<xsl:template name="STDR2_DATOS_OPERACION">
    <xsl:param name="ns" />
    <xsl:variable name="datOperacion" select="STDR2_DATOS_OPERACION" />
    <xsl:element name="wsb:canalOperacion" namespace="{$ns}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$datOperacion/STDR2_CANAL" />
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="wsb:codigoOficina" namespace="{$ns}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$datOperacion/STDR2_CODOFI" />
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="wsb:fechaOperacion" namespace="{$ns}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$datOperacion/STDR2_FECOPE" />
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="wsb:horaOperacion" namespace="{$ns}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$datOperacion/STDR2_HOROPE" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

`

Comment: Hello! If you have another question, then you really need to ask it as a whole new separate question in its own thread, rather than ask it as an answer to your existing question. Thanks!